# Installed 'github-autostatus' plugin not updating Job & stage monitoring status in GitHub

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, github-actions

Installed https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-autostatus/ plugin

```
Watches pipeline jobs and provides job and stage stats such as time and pass/fail. Can be configured to update GitHub commit status 
(one status per stage) and send stats to an InfluxDB instance, or StatsD collector, for build health monitoring of job/stage timing and success rate.
```

As highlighted in link, I am expecting this to appear in stage before PR merge to target button gets enabled. But post plugin installation & restart it's not appearing in PR.s

[image]

'Send to GitHub' is selected under 'Autostatus Config' under `Jenkins->Configure System`

[image]

Don't see any difference in behavior when new PR is created against target branch in Github.

Configured 'Poll SCM' to true on this branch to check behavior & build is getting triggered in Jenkins only once 'Merge' is complete, but not when PR is created & Review is pending. Am I missing something to achieve this setup?

Does post build steps in declarative pipeline needs to be added to explicitly updated?. Is there a documentation which details these steps please?.

Don't see configuration instruction on plugin site.

Comment: What do you see? Let's start with that. What is the log output when the action runs? What does your workflow file look like?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question without any additional info (like [commented by @smac89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60653217/installed-github-autostatus-plugin-not-updating-job-stage-monitoring-status/63907714#comment109366041_60653217)), but I try to give some general information about installing/using the plugin for anyone coming here by their very best search engine.

---

In general, to get it working, you need to install this plugin together with [GitHub Branch Source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/) (which is a dependency). For me, it works well with GitHub organizations (adding a new *GitHub Organization* pipeline and configure it with the correct GitHub credentials under *Projects* in the pipeline config). This will scan your GitHub organization for any repositories with a Jenkinsfile but you can add some filter to exclude repositories within the org pipeline configuration.
The pipeline reports then automatically all stage results to the corresponding commit and GitHub shows these results within the Pull Request when this commit is the latest on the linked branch.

But there seems to be an error with non-org pipelines, see [issue 86](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-autostatus-plugin/issues/86).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to post build status on github

```
void setBuildStatus(String message, String state) {
  step([
      $class: "GitHubCommitStatusSetter",
      reposSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredRepositorySource", url: "https://github.com/my-org/my-repo"],
      contextSource: [$class: "ManuallyEnteredCommitContextSource", context: "ci/jenkins/build-status"],
      errorHandlers: [[$class: "ChangingBuildStatusErrorHandler", result: "UNSTABLE"]],
      statusResultSource: [ $class: "ConditionalStatusResultSource", results: [[$class: "AnyBuildResult", message: message, state: state]] ]
  ]);
}

setBuildStatus("Build complete", "SUCCESS");
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?