# Enabling status check with Github from Jenkins build for pull request : Sorry, we couldn’t find any status checks in the last week for this repository

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-status-checks

Following above link to set up on enabling status check, but I see `Sorry, we couldn’t find any status checks in the last week for this repository` on step 7/8 on the document as I am not seeing that drop down. How can I enable it?.

[image]

Also looked at few referencing documentation : 
[building a CI server github](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/building-a-ci-server/)
& also [repo status git api](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.18/v3/repos/statuses/)

How do we leverage them to set status from Jenkins.  Is there a documentation which covers example for Jenkins please?. Does explicit post build step or similar to set status via rest api call?.

Referencing my earlier question which is with similar ask on enabling from Github UI as well: [installed-github-autostatus-plugin-not-updating-job-stage-monitoring-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60653217/installed-github-autostatus-plugin-not-updating-job-stage-monitoring-status)

Comment: You need to have a GitHub app installed, which will listen to the GitHub webhook. This is the related documentation:
https://developer.github.com/apps/quickstart-guides/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api/ Maybe this will help. It's an example using Circle CI:
https://dev.to/sebalinares/upgrading-your-personal-project-game-with-circleci-circleci-netlify-github-part-1-eng-5bp2

Comment: Though the "Sorry, we couldn't..." message looks a bit disappointing, there's nothing wrong with it. In case you configured everything well, having enabled the "Require status checks to pass before merging" checkbox, click Save. Then go and create a PR towards the corresponding branch and the PR checks should be triggered. If so, the next time you visit the branch rule page in GitHub, the "Sorry..." message will go away.